# Why MAC address representation is a bit different?

Tags: mac-address

I see that in ccna book the representation of a virtual MAC address is by for example :-
0000.0c07.ac0a 
Somewhere else it is, 00:00:0c:07:ac:0a.
In cmd it is, 00-00-0c-07-ac-0a.

Does this mean there is no specific way to represent it ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: If you're here looking for information about MAC addresses in the 00:00:0c:07:ac:XX range, then they're used in Cisco's [Hot Standby Router Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Standby_Router_Protocol) (HSRP).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MAC address in this case is actually 00000c07ac0a, the representation is just a way of formatting the MAC address so it can be easily read, and it can vary depending on what command you are using.  The actual address doesn't have any separators (: - or .).  There isn't a common standard way to represent the address, they are all interchangeable.